# Summation of series using definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, summation

I learned that definite integral gives the signed area under a curve by dividing the curve into small rectangular strips and "making" its width shrink to zero.

Using this knowledge summation of certain series can be found. I converted definite integral in this form

$$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{r=1}^{n} f\left( a + \left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)r \right) $$

However, another equivalent form is known to exist, provided below, and I find it much more convenient to use that form. I tried to manipulate the sum to arrive at the equivalent form but so far I've not able to succeed.

$$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=g(n)}^{h(n)} f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right),
\quad \text{where } \begin{cases}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{g(n)}{n} = a, \\ 
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{h(n)}{n} = b.
\end{cases} $$

Can someone help (give me a hint perhaps) on how to convert to the second much more convenient expression.

I find second expression much more convenient because the limits of integration can be very easily found using it.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: I've still not able to derive the equivalent relation mentioned above. Can someone hint me?

Comment: Hmmm.. why isn't someone responding to my question? Sorry if it sounds a bit silly question.

Comment: The notation is a bit unclear to me. For the second sum to make sense, it should hold that $g(n)$ and $h(n)$ are always integers with $g(n) \leq h(n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Could you give a practical example for the second expression?

Comment: @user Consider when lower index of summation is 1 and upper index is 2n. Limits on integration will be given by

Comment: ...a= 1/n (n tends to infinity) = 0 and b = 2n/n (n tends to infinity) = 2

Comment: @user Does this example makes question a bit more clear?

Comment: It would be better if you can give a question where the second formula (a product of cheap calculus textbooks from India) is more useful. One can then show how the problem can be solved using the standard definition.

Answer (score 1):

It more make sense that we focus on the behavior of $$\frac1n\sum_{r=h(n)}^{g(n)}f(r/n)$$
as $n\to \infty$. Think of the $1/n$ as the width of each subinterval of $[a,b]$, and think of $r/n$ as $x$-values in each subinterval. As $n\to\infty$, each subinterval approaches a single point, namely $\lim_{n\to\infty}r/n$. So it's just a sum of $\text{height}\times\text{width}$.